# Check if elements in array are elements in another array in Laravel Validator

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to validate an array by verifying that all the elements in an input is part of another array. For example, lets say I have three arrays:

```php
$foo = ['John', 'Terry', 'Kim'];
$bar = ['John', 'Kim'];
$sub = ['John', 'Ringo'];
```

and I have a function called `CompareArrays()`. Doing `CompareArrays($foo, $bar)` would result in `true` because all the elements in `$bar` exists in `$foo`. However, `CompareArrays($foo, $sub)` would result in `false` because `Ringo` doesn't exist in `foo`. Implementing this in vanilla php is

```php
!array_diff($foo, $bar)
```

How would I do this in a Laravel Validator **without making a custom rule** (v6.10) ?

Answer (score 0):

You may use `in_array:anotherfield.*` rule

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
//...

$request->validate([
    'arr1' => 'required|array',
    'arr2' => 'nullable|array',
    'arr2.*' => [Rule::requiredIf($request->filled('arr1')), 'in_array:arr1.*']
    /...
]);
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it if `arr1` is not part of the request?

Comment: You can merge your `arr1` into $request obj via `$request->request->add(['arr1' => ['items']]);`